# How to make TWebPanel have rounded corners?

Tags: css, delphi, delphi-11-alexandria, tms-web-core

I'm trying to get this done on TMS Web Core via Delphi code using.

```
procedure TForm1.WebFormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 pnlPersonalInfo.Margins.Left := 15;
 pnlPersonalInfo.Margins.Top := 15;
 pnlPersonalInfo.Margins.Right := 15;
 pnlPersonalInfo.Margins.Bottom := 15;


 phone.HTML.Text := GetBootstrapIcon('telephone-fill', 24, '#576A33');
 email.HTML.Text := GetBootstrapIcon('envelope-fill', 24, '#576A33');
 location.HTML.Text := GetBootstrapIcon('geo-alt-fill', 24, '#576A33');

 web.HTML.Text := GetBootstrapIcon('globe', 24, '#576A33');
 Github.HTML.Text := GetBootstrapIcon('github', 24, '#576A33');
end;
```

`pnlPersonalInfo` is the TWebPanel that I want to give rounded corners.

Comment: I would use Bootstrap Cards for this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/

Comment: @JohnEasley Why Bootstrap Cards?

Comment: @ShaunRoselt because it's responsive. The next question is how to align an image in the TWebPanel etc..  Cards handles all of that and looks great on any device.

Answer (score 3):

You can give any component rounded corners by using inline CSS. Here are three examples:

```
// Rounded corners for all four corners:
WebPanel1.ElementHandle.style.setProperty('border-radius','50px');

// Rounded corners for top-left and bottom-left corners:
WebPanel2.ElementHandle.style.setProperty('border-radius','50px 0 0 50px');

// Rounded corners for top-right and bottom-right corners:
WebPanel3.ElementHandle.style.setProperty('border-radius','0 50px 50px 0');
```

[image: Delphi TMS Web Core Panels with Rounded Corners]

Comment: this is the answer I was looking for, Thank you. 2nd Solution was the best in my case.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/), then you can use the [official Bootstrap Border Classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/borders/#radius).

You can add the classes to the `ElementClassName` property on the panels. Here are some examples of where I'm styling panels to have rounded corners and be blue using Bootstrap classes:

```
WebPanel1.ElementClassName := 'bg-primary text-black rounded';
WebPanel2.ElementClassName := 'bg-primary text-black rounded-top';
WebPanel3.ElementClassName := 'bg-primary text-black rounded-end';
WebPanel4.ElementClassName := 'bg-primary text-black rounded-bottom';
WebPanel5.ElementClassName := 'bg-primary text-black rounded-start';
WebPanel6.ElementClassName := 'bg-primary text-black rounded-circle';
```

[image: Delphi TMS Web Core Panels with rounded corners using Bootstrap]

---

You can also adjust the rounded sizes like in the following examples:

```
WebPanel1.ElementClassName := 'bg-primary text-black rounded-0';
WebPanel2.ElementClassName := 'bg-primary text-black rounded-1';
WebPanel3.ElementClassName := 'bg-primary text-black rounded-2';
WebPanel4.ElementClassName := 'bg-primary text-black rounded-3';
WebPanel5.ElementClassName := 'bg-primary text-black rounded-4';
WebPanel6.ElementClassName := 'bg-primary text-black rounded-5';
```

[image: Delphi TMS Web Core Panels with rounded corners using Bootstrap]

---

There are also some other class variations from Bootstrap 5.3+ such as:

```
WebPanel1.ElementClassName := 'bg-primary text-black rounded-bottom-1';
WebPanel2.ElementClassName := 'bg-primary text-black rounded-start-2';
WebPanel3.ElementClassName := 'bg-primary text-black rounded-end-circle';
WebPanel4.ElementClassName := 'bg-primary text-black rounded-start-pill';
WebPanel5.ElementClassName := 'bg-primary text-black rounded-5 rounded-top-0';
```