# Setting a border on a TWebLabel not working

Tags: css, delphi, delphi-11-alexandria, tms, tms-web-core

I am trying to do this on a TWebLabel, giving it a solid border of 5px and coloring it.
I attempted to use .setProperty as mentioned in this post ([How to make TWebPanel have rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77249398/how-to-make-twebpanel-have-rounded-corners))
I attempted this on the TWebLabel (lblHome)

```
lblHome.ElementHandle.style.setProperty('border-top', '5px solid #da3b26');
```

But nothing happens?

Comment: Can you add the label's DFM properties to your question please? Maybe one of the other properties that you have set is conflicting with this. I tried the exact same code on my Delphi with a label and it's working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this on my side and it seems to be working. I made a blank new app, placed a `TWebLabel` onto the form, and added the exact same code into a button click event and it's added the `border-top` to the label as can be seen by this image below:

[image: Button, Label, Memo]

So perhaps your label has some other properties that are stopping the `border-top` from working?

Maybe the label's border/corners are out of bounds, so the border is there, but you just can't see it?

Maybe also delete the label and re-add it to the form and then try again.

---

The below code should work to add a border:

```
WebLabel1.ElementHandle.style.setProperty('border', '5px solid #da3b26');
```

But you can also add a border with the following code:

```
var
  BorderStyle: String;
begin
  BorderStyle := WebLabel1.ElementHandle.getAttribute('style') + ';border: 5px solid #da3b26;';
  WebLabel1.ElementHandle.setAttribute('style',BorderStyle);
end;
```

And if you're using Bootstrap:

```
WebPanel1.ElementClassName := 'border border-5 border-danger';
```

`border-top` for only the top border using Bootstrap.